# Update primary key

Tags: primary-key

I want to update a primary key column, but the change should cascade to all other child tables where this primary key is used as foreign key.

Example: table1 has column "slug" as primary key. One row has the slug "foo" which should be "bar". The table "table1" is used in ten other tables as foreign key (child tables).

I is quite easy to create do it like this:

```
begin;
update table1 ...
update table_child1 ...
update table_child2 ...
...
commit;
```

Is there a tool to make this easier? For example a tool which looks at the database layout, and creates the update commands.

I use PostgreSQL 9.1, but a portable solution is prefered.

Update: I dont' want/can change the database schema to include "on update cascade" at db level.

Answer (score 1):

If your `FOREIGN` keys are defined with the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option, then you need to do nothing more that update the parent table.

But it seems that the `ON UPDATE` options are not yet properly implemented in Django.

Comment: See this [Ticket #7539 : Add ON DELETE and ON UPDATE support to Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7539)

Comment: No, there is no "ON UPDATE CASCADE", and I can't add it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, only `ON DELETE` is supported, my wrong.

Comment: Update: I dont' want/can change the database schema to include "on update cascade" at db level.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a management command for my environment (django).

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2691/